# Operations with list

Tags: c, list, struct, operation

Here a slice of code that doesnt work.
The problem is when I try to delete a node. 
I notice when I look at the memory addresses, the pointer *next is pointing a incorrect node. Then when I try to delete a node, the list become only with the firts and last node. It loses the intermediary nodes.

```
typedef struct node{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
}node;

typedef struct struct_list{
    int count;
    struct node *header;
    struct node *tailer;
}struct_list;

void init_list(struct_list *list)
{
    (*list).count=0;
    (*list).header=(*list).tailer=NULL;
}



void insert(struct_list *list, int new_value){

    node *new_node=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    (*new_node).value=new_value;
    (*new_node).next=NULL;


    if(((*list).header)!=NULL){

        (*new_node).prev=(*list).tailer;
        list->tailer->next=new_node;
        (*list).tailer=new_node;

    }

    if(((*list).header)==NULL){
        (*new_node).prev=NULL;
        (*list).header=(*list).tailer=new_node;
    }

    (*list).count++;

};

void delete(struct_list *list, int j){

    node tmp;



    tmp=sub_search((*list).header, j);// This function sub_search
    \\works and return the address of node I want delete





    if(tmp.next != NULL){
    tmp.prev->next=tmp.next;
    tmp.next->prev=tmp.prev;
    }else{
    tmp.prev->next=NULL;
    }
    free(&tmp); // Here the new symbol & because free needs the 
    //address.Its just for testing. 
    list->count--;

}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n,i,new_value,j;
    struct_list list;
    init_list(&list);

    printf("How much nodes do you want?:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {printf("Insert node of node:\n");
    scanf("%d",&new_value);
    insert(&list, new_value);
    }  

    printf("Insert node to delete:\n");
    scanf("%d",&j);

    delete(&list, j);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You do know about the "arrow" in C? For example, if you have a pointer to a structure, lets say `list`, and you want to access a member variable in that structure, you can either do `(*list).member` *or* (which is more common) do `list->member`. Well now I see that you *do* know about it, because you use it in some places.

Comment: As for your question, can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? In other words, can you please make a small and simple `main` function that calls the functions you show, so it's easier for us to understand what's happening. By the way, do the code you show even compile? In the `delete` function you declare `tmp` as a *pointer* to the `node` structure, but you use e.g. `tmp.next` which should give you a compiler error.

Comment: Ok, sorry dude. I did it now.

Comment: By the way, you need to check if the node you're removing is the *first* node, not only the last node. Because, what is `tmp->prev` for the first node?

Comment: I suggest you take a piece of paper, draw nodes and arrows of which node/field points to which node/field, then use an eraser and simulate an insert/delete, etc. You might see amazing results, such as "Oh, stupid me..." Anyway, that is what we do, either in our (experienced) memory, or actually on paper.

Comment: It's a bidirectional list, so list.prev is necessary to go back.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, I would be thoroughly surprised if your compiler accepts the code snippet you posted. The problem is that you're mangling `.` and `->` inside of your `delete` function. These two lines are to blame:

```
tmp.prev->next=tmp.next;
tmp.next->prev=tmp.prev;
```

Now, to analyze what this is doing, let's desugar the `->` syntax (extra parentheses added for clarity):

```
(*(tmp.prev)).next=tmp.next;
(*(tmp.next)).prev=tmp.prev;
```

Looking at this, you can see that your code is saying that it needs to access the `prev` field of the `struct` (NB: **not** `struct*`) within the variable `tmp`, and it's expecting *that* to be a `struct*` pointing to a `struct` with a `next` field. As such, you get behavior you don't want. I did a quick test with the following, which should work:

```
tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
```

Desugaring this, we see that it does what we want (everything is correctly expected to be `struct*`):

```
(*((*tmp).prev)).next = (*(tmp)).next;
(*((*tmp).next)).prev = (*(tmp)).prev;
```

Also, two more comments about your code:

1. As a personal preference, I've always thought using `(*ptr).field` instead of `ptr->field` to be poor style. On top of that, avoiding it will prevent bugs like this.
2. Unless I'm mistaken, it looks like you're forgetting to update `tailer` after deleting :)

The following is just conjecture, but I think it's fun:

Let's say your compiler accepted the code snippet you posted. Why didn't it crash? I think what might have happened went something like this:

Your compiler was expecting `tmp` to be a `node` instead of a `node*`. What does that mean? Well, a `node` (note: this varies from compiler to compiler) looks something like this in memory:

```
+----------+
|  value   |
+----------+
|   prev   |
+----------+
|   next   |
+----------+
```

Let's say, for the sake of exercise, that these are all `int`-sized entries (32 bits).

A pointer is the size of only one of these blocks:

```
+----------+
|  *tmp    |
+----------+
|   XXXX   |
+----------+
|   XXXX   |
+----------+
```

Where `XXXX` is who-knows-what.

What happens when you try and look up those fields on `tmp` as a normal struct? You get those `XXXX` contents (since they are, relative to where a `node` begins in memory, the locations of those fields).

Now, if your stack is set up in *just* the right way, you might get behavior like, oh, I don't know... always excising all but the header and tailer of the list.

Debugging in C is fun.

Comment: I made some changes now. This works but does not accept ' free '.